# extract everything after "[0-9]. " until line end in unix command

Tags: text-processing

Suppose I have file which has entries like

```
5. variable1:
10. variable7:
230. variable21803:
```

I would like to get all the variable as an output without the "5. " etc. What I've tried is

`grep -Po '(?<=^[0-9] )[.\n]+`

However, this returns nothing. I'm relatively new to unix so any help would be much appreciated.

Here is an updated test with spaces in front

```
    ranodm text 
   1. variable1:
   2. variable10:
   3. variable302:
```

Comment: Why are you mentioning `:` in your regular expression, but no dot?

Comment: So now there's two input files with different data? What should the corresponding output for both of them be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grep` utility is not great for editing within lines. Its standard usage is to extract lines matching a specific regular expression, or string.  The `sed` editor is more commonly used for doing edits like these.

The following command show how to use `sed` to delete everything before the first space character on each line of a file:

```bsh
$ sed 's/[^ ]* //' file
variable1
variable7
variable21803
```

The expression `s/[^ ]* //` matches zero or more non-space characters, followed by a space.  It then replaces the matched substring with nothing (i.e., deletes it).

If you need to match a whole number followed by a dot before the space, at the start of the line, you may do so:

```bsh
$ sed 's/^[[:digit:]]*\. //' file
variable1
variable7
variable21803
```

This matches zero or more digits at the start of the line, followed by a dot and a space.  These, if matched, are removed.

---

The updated question asks for something quite different, which includes removing data at both ends of each line.

You can do this in several ways, and the command below shows  how to remove the first bit of the line, up to the last space, and then remove the final `:`, on all lines that end with a `:`, given the data in your question:

```bsh
$ sed '/:$/ { s///; s/.* //; }' file
    ranodm text
variable1
variable10
variable302
```

Or, if you don't want that random text at the start:

```bsh
$ sed -n '/:$/ { s///; s/.* //p; }' file
variable1
variable10
variable302
```

Comment: many thanks for your help! one last question, if i have some spaces in front of each line, it seems not to work. can we adjust 'sed 's/[^ ]* //' to deal with this? I've attached a text file as an example. Ideally i would also remove the ":" at the end. many thanks

Comment: @swissy Consider updating your question with what you are actually asking for, with representative sample data and an example of what that sample data would look lke after the processing.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
raku -e 'lines.comb(/ variable \d+ /).join("\n").put;'
```

Sample Input:

```
5. variable1:
10. variable7:
230. variable21803:

    ranodm text 

   1. variable1:
   2. variable10:
   3. variable302:
```

Sample Output:

```
variable1
variable7
variable21803
variable1
variable10
variable302
```

Above is a solution coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programmming languages. Briefly, Raku provides a `comb` routine which takes a `/…/` regex matcher. When called at the command line, `lines` are read, `comb`-ed through to find the (whitespace-insignificant) `variable \d+` pattern, and matches are returned.

Remove the `join("\n")` call if you'd like all matches returned on one line:

```perl
raku -e 'lines.comb(/ variable \d+ /).put;' file
variable1 variable7 variable21803 variable1 variable10 variable302
```

Of course, there are other solutions available in Raku, including solutions using the familiar `s///` substitution operator (like the `sed` solution posted elsewhere in this thread). Below is another Raku solution, one that preserves line spacing:

```perl
raku -ne 'put m:g/ [variable \d+] /;' file
variable1
variable7
variable21803



variable1
variable10
variable302
```

https://raku.org